# GPS Loading Incorrect Debugger Version (GDB)

Tags: gdb, gnat-gps

I'm using GPS version 6.2.2 (20160527) with GNAT Pro 7.4.2 (20160527-49). The debugger that ships with this version of GNAT is 7.10 for GNAT Pro 7.4.2 [rev=gdb-7.10-ref-125-g3d2bab0].

Using GPS, the way to launch the debug session is to go to Debug->Initialize. When I do this, a debugger console pops up down below. Typing `show version` into the console returns the OS debugger for Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL6) which shipped with the OS, as opposed to the correct version supplied with GNAT.

However, typing `which gdb` at the command line (outside of GPS) returns the correct version of the debugger installed with GNAT.

How do I get GPS to launch the correct debugger? Where is it getting the OS debugger from?

Comment: I would have guessed that GPS is using the `PATH` environment variable it was started with, to search for the `gdb` executable.  Have you verified that that is not the case?

Comment: I don’t know which path variable GPS is using, or why it would be different from the one configured when I open a terminal window. But, I did try running it from the command line (as opposed to clicking the desktop icon) and it opened the correct GDB version, Is there a way to check the PATH of the desktop?

Comment: I'm sure there is, but I don't know which desktop manager comes with RHEL6.